# JavaScript in Google Modules (DATE)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a field in my google module where the DATE of the next meeting is automatically updated by a script.

Thanks to a great user (mrdeadsven) of stackoverflow I found the right script for my web page.

This is the script:

```
    <script>
        var d = new Date();
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + (3 + 7 - d.getDay()) % 7);

        if(d.getDay() == 3 && d.getHours() > 19 && d.getMinutes() > 30)
    {
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + (3 + 7 - d.getDay()));
    }

var options = {'weekday': 'long', 'month': 'long', 'day': '2-digit', 'year': 'numeric'};
var date = d.toLocaleString('it-IT', options);
document.getElementById('nextMeeting').innerHTML = date.toString();
</script>
```

It works fine on my html page, but I wonder if it also works on google modules and I would like to know if you have any suggestion to how implement it on the google module: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/18QZFehAHijkDEydq30ceGACIAOIlgbCRdmjGJKXaSAc/edit?addon_dry_run=AAnXSK_Atp7KAGo5oZOgBIhpswtGE9YknoyXr-BOOCFTep5B8tlxxK3K1ffWSF5Fh1qUFdyvFdR9j5wm6soDNmFN0VdKR4pxLmdkmo60XQ5E3IChltbpYOtOpuInP-dxRF1gG3h74cO1.

I want that when a user see my Google Module to apply for the meeting, the DATE of the meeting is automatically updated after 20:30 of every wednesday for the next wed.

For example, today is 18th july wed... If you join now (18:39) in my module you will see a field telling you: MEETING DATE - > 18 Luglio 2018 .

After 20:30 the script must change the date to next wed, for ex -> July 25th, and so.

Anyone could help me?

Comment: You cannot programmatically alter Google Forms as viewed by respondents. I'm also not sure what you mean by "Google module" - do you mean [Google Forms](https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/)?

Comment: Yes I mean Google Forms!

Comment: you should edit your post and the tags to correctly represent your question. Consider also my previous comment.

Comment: How can I tag it ?